# Apply predicate on every list element

Tags: list, lambda, prolog

I need to implement `y = 1/x` on a list of numbers.

I.e.

```
inv (List1, ResultingList).

inv ([2 , 1 , 0 , 0.25 ] , R).
R = [ 0.5, 1, inf, 4.0 ].
```

I've try with a recursive function but it doesn't work.

this is my "solution":

```
    inv([], []).
    inv(list, R):- list == [H|T], T \== [], Y is (1/H),
        append(R, Y, R), inv(T);
        list = [H|T], T == [], R = T;
        list = [H|T], H == [0], append(R, "inf", R).
```

I know that there are a lot of mistakes but I don't find the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names start with a capital letter, and `(==)/2` is only used for very rare cases. Further `append/3` is rarely used for such predicates. Briefly:

```
inv([], []).
inv([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
   Y is 1/X,
   inv(Xs, Ys).
```

Or:

```
reciprocal(X, Y) :-
   Y is 1/X.

inv(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(reciprocal, Xs, Ys)
```

or using `library(lambda)`

```
inv(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(\X^Y^(Y is 1/X), Xs, Ys).
```

note that most commonly `maplist/3` is called directly without the auxiliary definition.

There is, however, no standard for the usage of a continuation value `inf`.  In case you really need it, you have have to make that extra handling yourself.